# CSS Negative Margins to counter wrapper element padding

Tags: html, css

Why is the negative margin assigned to the `.alert` class not working. I want the `.alert` class to occupy the complete width of the container. I do not want to assign separate paddings to all elements since only the `.alert` element will have to occupy the entire width of the `.outer` container. all other elements should have a padding assigned to the outer container.

```css
.outer{
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}

.alert{
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  margin: -20px -20px 0 -20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.other{
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="alert">Hello! This is an alert</div>
  <div class="other">Content. Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="other">Content. Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="other">Content. Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="other">Content. Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="other">Content. Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`width: 100%` makes the content area of `.alert` to be as wide as its containing block, established by `.outer`. You want it to grow via negative margins, but that `width` declaration prevents the enlargement. Use the default `width: auto` instead.

```css
.outer {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}
.alert {
  height: 20%;
  background: blue;
  margin: -20px -20px 0 -20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
.other {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="alert">Hello!</div>
  <div class="other">Content</div>
  <div class="other">Content</div>
  <div class="other">Content</div>
  <div class="other">Content</div>
  <div class="other">Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative with `width:100%`

As said in other answer, `Width:auto` is propably the best solution. But if you want to keep the `Width:100%` you could:

- Set width of `alert`to `100%`
- Set the same padding for `alert`and is parent `outer`
- Add a megative marign equals to padding to move `alert`on left

```css
.outer{
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}

.alert{
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top:-20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.other{
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="alert">Hello! This is an alert</div>
  <div class="other">Content. Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="other">Content. Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="other">Content. Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="other">Content. Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="other">Content. Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```